# Android Manifest Error from Admob

Tags: java, android, admob

I am trying to integrate AdMob and I have come to the point where I have to add this line to my manifest and I keep getting this error. This is the exemplar from this link http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

> error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value
>   'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').

Answer (score 7):

You must build against API 13 (Android 3.2). You will leave the `android:minSdkVersion` the same in your Manifest, but you will have to build against 3.2.

In Eclipse(I assume?), right click on the project > Properties > Android (on the left) > then choose 3.2 and click 'OK'.

This will not cause problems - your app will still run fine on older devices. But do be careful and make sure you don't use new code for old devices.

What I generally do to make this easy is before exporting to publish I switch the target back to my minimum, make sure there are no compile errors, then I switch it back to 3.2 - just a tip.

Comment: Sorry what!? Thank you for your reply this has taken me by surprise. At the moment I target 1.6. Is this an error in eclipse?

Comment: It is not an error with Eclipse or with anything, for that matter. Some of the attributes that go inside of `configChanges` were introduced in 3.2. And you can't remove them from `configChanges` because then your ads would not show.

Comment: Older devices will ignore any `configChanges` they don't recognize, but it is a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in my manifest.  The target Android SDK is Version 8.  Using AdMob SDK 4.1.1.

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"/>
```

Comment: That means your Admob SDK is likely outdated. The current docs at http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html say "[make sure] that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13)."

Comment: Yes.  The current version is 4.3.1.  But I am pretty sure you can get it to work by excluding the unsupported options.

Comment: I tried to do so in my app, then when I ran it on my test device instead of showing an ad it gave me a message saying something about the manifest options that I needed and did not have.

Comment: No Frohnzie, it doesn't work, latest SDK thrown an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here after playing around with it I found the right combination apparently adMob requires a few settings.  I am building using the 3.2 SDK but I have tested this and it runs on 2.3.3 just for FYI.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="10" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="16" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Then my default.properties must have

```
target=android-10
```

Also the project.properties had to have

```
target=android-13
```

Then add your `<com.google.ads.AdView .../>` to your XML layout or call it from code and you should be in business.

Answer (score 0):

you can ignore the latest changes, and use the older one instead

configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"